# Minidom on Python: memory issue

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm using minidom on Python to parse an xml file.  I understand that it's a somewhat slow process and takes up a substantial amount of memory.  I'm using a for-next loop.  The files happen to be large, but I'm fine with the time it takes to parse the first one.  The first one takes a couple of minutes but when looping back and running the same parse function, it took 30 minutes to do so.  Must be a memory issue.  Is there anything I could do to dump the memory so that those subsequent files don't take much longer?

Example in Python (excluding the other things I do with the variable xmldoc once it's parsed):

```
for filename in filelist:
   file = open(filename,'r')
   xmldoc = minidom.parse(file)
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have multiple files, that all have the same format, so you would expect `minidom` to recognize and [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the structure? If so, that is not possible with `minidom` (or any xml parsing library that I am familiar with).

Comment: Is one of the things you "do with the variable xmldoc", `del xmldoc`? Also, are the 2nd and first files more-or-less identical in size, number of xml elements, etc?

Comment: Thank you both.  Yes, multiple xml files with the same structure and around the same size.  They work perfectly fine on their own.  I used 'xmldoc = None' right before looping again, but perhaps 'del xmldoc' will work better.